# make the button with the array of coordinates that will relocate you when you push it

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, coordinates

I have a google map, and I have a lot of coordinates of different locations.
And what I have to do - it is a button, and when you push it, it will relocate user to different coordinates

I'm confused how to do it

I have made such example only with different buttons  - http://jsfiddle.net/wb7eqbnj/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <input type="button" id="panLA" value="Pan To Los Angeles" />
    <input type="button" id="panLB" value="Pan To Long Beach" />

    <input type="button" id="london" value="london" />
    <input type="button" id="leeds" value="leeds" />
    <input type="button" id="cambridge" value="cambridge" />
    <input type="button" id="edinburg" value="edinburg" />
    <input type="button" id="miami" value="miami" />

</div>
<div id="data"></div>
```

And JS :

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();

    $("#menu").on("click", "#panLA", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437);
        marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#menu").on("click", "#panLB", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.70131647557699, -118.15599389648437);

marker.setPosition(laLatLng);        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });

    $("#menu").on("click", "#london", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.501417, -0.020886);;marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#menu").on("click", "#leeds", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.708214, -1.621459);marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#menu").on("click", "#cambridge", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.231462, 0.147424);marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#menu").on("click", "#edinburg", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.94756, -3.211026);marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#menu").on("click", "#miami", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.77248, -80.186847);marker.setPosition(laLatLng);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
});

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5120, -0.12);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles:[{
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#d2d2d2"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit.line",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }, {
                "color": "#b5b5b5"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "color": "#b4b4b4"
            }, {
                "weight": 0.1
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#b4b4b4"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#808080"
            }, {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#b4b4b4"
            }]
        }]

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: "http://unfold.no/css/images/map-marker.png",
        map: map
    });
}
```

But I really  dont know how to make one button with all that coordinates

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is store the lat lang within the html attributes.

```
<input type="button" data-attr-lat="34.01131647557699" data-attr-lng="-118.25599389648437" id="panLA" value="Pan To Los Angeles" />
```

In your jquery, you should be able to have one function:

```
$('menu input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
     let lat = $(this).attr('data-attr-lat');
     let lng = $(this).attr('data-attr-lng');
     let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     marker.setPosition(latLng);
     map.panTo(latLng);
});
```

How it works:

```
$('menu input[type="button"]')
```

The above code selects each button within the menu

```
.on('click',function(){})
```

The above code attaches an on click listener to each button returned by `$('menu input[type="button"]')`

```
   let lat = $(this).attr('data-attr-lat');
   let lng = $(this).attr('data-attr-lng');
```

Within the above code `$(this)` refers to the button that triggered the event ( the button that was clicked), we then retrieve the lat and lang from it using the jquery `.attr()` function. These are then used to construct our new google maps LatLng object.

**UPDATE after realizing you only need one button:**

Html:

```
<div id="menu">
<input type="button" id="panBtn" value="Pan To Los Angeles" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const coordinateArray = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.70131647557699, -118.15599389648437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.501417, -0.020886),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.708214, -1.621459),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.231462, 0.147424),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.94756, -3.211026),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.77248, -80.186847)
 ];
 let currentPosition = 0;
 $('#menu #panBtn').on('click',function(){
     let latLng = coordinateArray[(currentPosition++)%coordinateArray.length];
     marker.setPosition(latLng);
     map.panTo(latLng);
});
```

Comment: You mean that I will need to set value to every input  and than hide that all inputs and make visible only one button and then this fuction on jQuery will make the relocation to each input with coordinates?

Comment: No no, you just need to add data-attr-lat and data-attr-lng to each of the buttons as attrributes like I have shown above. Then when any of the buttons within the menu is clicked the function I have created above will get called and retrieve the attributes from whichever button was clicked

Comment: $(this) in jquery refers to the element that triggered the event, in this case it will be the button that was clicked. That is how we can retrieve the attributes for the button that was clicked.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide more explaination

Comment: the problem is that I need only one button, and when I push this button it will take me to different coordinates on the map

Comment: Like I dont need a lot of buttons, I need only one, and with every push, it will show me every new coordinate